# Sentences division

Tags: string, text, split, divide, sentence

I have to divide text for separated sentences.

Ok. It seem be very simple.

Just search for the "." or "?" or "!" and add next sentence to the array.

But unfortunately is not so great and simple.

How can I avoid situation when:

Washington, D.C.

will be splitted  for: "Washington, D" and "C".

OR

“One time we set off an explosive under the chair of our teacher, Mrs. Thurman."

Is splitted on:

"One time we set off an explosive under the chair of our teacher, Mrs"

And

"Thurman"

Maybe is the database with acronyms which contains "." ?

Thanks for tips in advance!

Comment: Sentences **should** really be separated by `.`, `?` or `!` and at least one character of whitespace. If you can guarantee that for your input then you could split on that instead of the single characters.

Comment: But there are acronyms as: Mrs.

Comment: And what if the sentence is quoted by ''? Should the quotes be included?

Comment: Of course. Why not ?  I just wanted to split the text to sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [NLTK](http://nltk.org/). It has out-of-the-box solutions for the problems you described

Comment: What's about using  http://search.cpan.org/~shlomoy/Lingua-EN-Sentence-0.25/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm